# Is there a toleration which lets a workload get deployed to every node including master in the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a toleration which lets workloads get deployed to every node including master nodes in the cluster regardless of any taints that any node has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This toleration will deploy your workload into every node including master nodes in your kubernetes cluster regardless of any taints on any nodes.

```
tolerations:
   - operator: Exists
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy in every node, why not using a daemonset instead?